# Tastypie : Authentication for GET and Anonymous for POST

Tags: python, django, api, rest, tastypie

I use Django/Tastypie to manage my user collection.

Is it possible to allow anonymous users to POST in the API (when creating a new user at some endpoint) and restrict authenticated users to GET only their own user, but not all the users ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the easiest thing to do was subclass the Authentication class I'm using.  Just override the `is_authenticated` method to return `True` when the method is POST.

```
class AnonymousPostAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):
    """ No auth on post / for user creation """

    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        """ If POST, don't check auth, otherwise fall back to parent """

        if request.method == "POST":
            return True
        else:
            return super(AnonymousPostAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)
```

I put my validation in a subclass of `Validation` and override `is_valid`.

I do the GET filtering the same way Sampson does it above.

Comment: Thank you. Works wonderfully. I modified the code a little as I needed to disable authentication just for GET and keep it for all the other methods.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to do both.

Here's a simple example of how you would let an authenticated user GET only their own user JSON and not from all the other users: (Assuming you are using Django's built-in user infrastructure):

```
# In api.py (or resource.py):
...
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie import fields
from models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from tastypie.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization
...

# REST endpoint for authenticating user accounts
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'auth/user'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(username=request.user)
```

And here is a simple example of how you would let an anonymous user POST to create a new user (Caveat: this doesn't use Tastypie, strictly speaking)

```
# In views.py:
...
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.http import Http404
from django.utils import timezone
from models import *
from api import *
from django.utils import simplejson
...

# REST endpoint for user registration
# Enforces server-side mediation (input validation)
# On failure, raises Http404
# On success, redirects to registration success page
def register_user(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404('Only POSTs are allowed')

    # acquire params
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    repeatpw = request.POST['repeatpw']
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']

    # Server-side mediation to check for invalid input
    if username == '' or username is None:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: Invalid Username')

    if len(username) > 30:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: username must be 30 characters or fewer')

    if len(first_name) > 30:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: first name must be 30 characters or fewer')

    if len(last_name) > 30:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: last name msut be 30 characters or fewer')

    if len(password) < 4:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: Password too short')

    if password != repeatpw:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: Password Mismatch')

    # This try-except block checks existence of username conflict
    try:
        test_user_exists = User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
        if test_user_exists != None:
            raise Http404('Server-side mediation: Username exists')
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    # Input passes all tests, proceed with user creation
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, 'default@nomail.com', password)
    group = Group.objects.get(name='Standard')
    user.first_name = first_name
    user.last_name = last_name
    user.groups.add(group)
    user.is_staff = False    
    user.save()

    # Build confirmation JSON
    confirmation = {
            'action': 'register_user',
            'username': username,
            'success': 'yes',
    }

    json_return = simplejson.dumps(confirmation)

    # return JSON of the success confirmation
    return HttpResponse(json_return, mimetype='application/json')
```

Based on that, here's a script of how you might create a new user through the REST endpoint using curl:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Usage: ./register_user username password repeatpw first_name last_name"
curl -v -d "username=$1&password=$2&repeatpw=$3&first_name=$4&last_name=$5" http://127.0.0.1:8000/register_user/ > result
```

Comment: Is it the only way to solve my issue ?
Because, as you say "this doesn't use Tastypie, strictly speaking"

Comment: No, this is not the only way; but as you read the code you can tell that it's pretty straight-forward for a solution(most of it is input validation). The idea is that you don't have to use Tastypie for everything. There is another way to do it with Tastypie, but it's more complicated. More generally speaking, if you just use a technology / piece of software to solve a problem without considering if it's the best fit, or if there is a better / simpler way of doing it, you are at risk for the gold-hammer antipattern: http://codebalance.blogspot.ca/2010/10/software-antipatterns-golden-hammer.html